# Sending huge CSV file as attachment in mail, I am getting very late response and sometimes request gets timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, delayed-job

I am having about 30,000 of orders(records).
And from controller i send an email with CSV of orders(records) using Delayed Job for background processing. Code is like -

```
OrderNotifier.delay.send_orders_csv(current_user, arranged_orders)
```

And in mailer -

```
  def send_orders_csv(logged_in_user, orders)
     @user = logged_in_user
     attachments['orders.csv'] = { mime_type: 'text/csv', content: Order.orders_csv(logged_in_user, orders) }
     mail(to: logged_in_user.email, subject: 'Orders CSV')
  end
```

And when it inserts row into Delayed::Job it takes a lot time because there are almost 30,000 of records that i need to send as CSV attachment.
I have tried with increasing delayed_job workers. But it didn't resolve it.

How can i send an email with the huge amount of records in CSV file at once?

Answer (score 1):

probably better to zip CSV file or send link to file

Comment: Problem is variable orders which is having large amount of data and when Job is inserted into Delayed::Job it actually stores that variable. And thats is the reason behind request timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to this.
As i mentioned in i am using delayed job and i was passing huge data to mailer's method and it means delayed job was storing that object's meta-data. And for storing the meta-data of around 30k records, So I passed filter paramater's to mailer's method as

```
def send_orders_csv(logged_in_user, orders_params)
  orders = Order.fetch(orders_params)
  @user = logged_in_user
  attachments['orders.csv'] = { mime_type: 'text/csv', content: Order.orders_csv(logged_in_user, orders) }
  mail(to: logged_in_user.email, subject: 'Orders CSV')
end
```

- And One more thing inside method which is generating CSV i,e 'orders_csv' use find_in_batches (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html), which will not hold the wholes objects but will hold objects in batches and release memory once it is done with the one batch of objects.

This also reduced the space and time complexity.